# App Store price drops and updates info

Tags: ios, app-store, itunes

I found a couple of websites which somehow collect App store price changes, updates, etc.
My question is - where does websites like:

1. [148apps.com](http://www.148apps.com)
2. [appdropp.com](http://www.appdropp.com)
3. etc.

get their info? I signed up as Apple affiliate and found that I can request apps info using the `search or lookup` APIs. But I can't send thousands of requests to check all apps day by day, it seems to be a huge task.

Is there any other available option to get this info?

Comment: This question is relevant for here, please ask in Apple store.

Comment: did you find any result related to price drop apps rss?

Answer (score 1):

They may be using this, [Enterprise Partner Feed](https://affiliate.itunes.apple.com/resources/documentation/itunes-enterprise-partner-feed/)

It looks like it would provide what you're looking.

Comment: Updated the link. In the future, if the link breaks, you can do a search for "Enterprise Partner Feed" which brought it right up for me.

Answer (score 0):

They are using EPF feed, provided by Apple. 
You can check their Python tool to import feed to database.

You can also take a look on websites like:
http://www.apptweak.com, or http://www.appsocean.com

If you know PHP (for example), you can write a simple spider to grab price drops and updates.
Just read more about PHP CURL library.